# How to properly use the each() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
  <div class="io-section-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="advanced">Eat</li>
    <li class="advanced">Sleep</li>
    <li class="advanced">Be merry</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I have the jQuery (which is tied to a click() handler:

```
$('io-section-header').each(function() {
                $("li").siblings(".advanced").toggle('fast',function(){});
            });
```

Why aren't the list items toggling?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `.` in your selector to denote a class.

Comment: Well, break the problem down in parts -- does `each` get called? If so, if does `$("li")` -- and furthermore, does `siblings(".advanced")` -- evaluate as expected? -1 for lack of proper debugging/problem explanation. (And, as Brad points out, *how is* the "current element" each iteration being used?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you actually need the `each()` statement for what you are trying to do.  This should work fine.

```
$('.io-section-header li').siblings(".advanced").toggle('fast');
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8kpcn/1/

---

In fact this will do the same thing as well

```
$('.io-section-header li.advanced').toggle('fast');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kpcn/2/

Comment: Actually, just `$('.io-section-header li.advanced').toggle('fast')` should work. The call to `siblings()` doesn't seem to serve a purpose.

Comment: @Sii Yep I was adding that as you made a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add a dot before your class selector.

```
$('.io-section-header').each(function() {
                $("li").siblings(".advanced").toggle('fast',function(){});
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/ddR9R/)

Answer (score 2):

The callback function needs some parameters.

```
$('.io-section-header').each(function(index, Element) {
    //Do whatever you need to do with each of them here.
    //The current element in this iteration is in `Element`
});
```

Comment: The parameters are not always necessary. And I do not believe this is the direct issue that OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @pst, yes, but he wasn't using `this`, so I assumed this is where the disconnect was.  @John, I'm aware they weren't always necessary... I thought he was wondering why he couldn't select just the elements he wanted.  If I am mistaken, I will delete this answer.

Comment: Technically, no. In jQuery, the value of `this` in the callback is bound to the current element.

Comment: @Brad Good call, I read over it entirely! You are indeed correct that the "element" is entirely not being used, I think also including being able to use `this` would make this answer more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.io-section-header li').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".advanced").toggle('fast');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/8kpcn/)